# Type that transform entries values?

Tags: typescript, types

I would like to define a type like:

```js
declare type TheOneMillionDollarType<
    Entry extends [string, any], 
    TrMap extends [Entry[1], any]
> = /* TODO */unknown;
```

Such that here:

```js
type Input = [ "foo", string ] | [ "bar", number ];

type TrMap = [ string, "string !" ] | [ number, "number !" ];

type Expected = [ "foo", "string !" ] | [ "bar", "number !" ];

type Got = TheOneMillionDollarType<Input, TrMap>;
```

`Expected` and `Got` would be the same type.

Very concretely. I would like [the code of this playground](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-nb2l8g?file=index.ts) to compile.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mAvb4W) work for you?  With just the single use case it's hard to tell, since there are likely lots of edge cases (what if you have `["foo", string | number]`, or `["foo", unknown]`, etc? What if the map looks like `[string | number, "xyz!"]`? What do you want to see?)  If you are happy with the version I wrote above I can write up an answer; otherwise, please [edit] the code here to show unsatisfied use cases.

Comment: Congrats, you solved it! It compiles so it work for me. Please submit your answer and I will accept it. Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to define it like this:

```
type TheOneMillionDollarType<
  E extends [string, any],
  M extends [E[1], any]
  > = E extends unknown ? [E[0], Extract<M, [E[1], any]>[1]] : never;
```

The type `E extends unknown ? ... : never` looks like a no-op, but it's actually a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) that splits `E` into its [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) members, evaluates the `...` part for each one, and then unions (unites? unionizes?  unifies? whatever) the results back together at the end.

That type is `[E[0], Extract<M, [E[1], any]>[1]]`, a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) like you want where the first element is the same as the first element of `E`.  The second element uses [the `Extract<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) to filter the `M` union and find any member(s) assignable to `[E[1], any]`.  That means we are selecting any member from `M` where the first element is assignable to the second element of `E`.  Once we get that, we then index into it (`[1]`) to get its second element.

And that works for your example at least:

```
type Got = TheOneMillionDollarType<Input, TrMap>;
// type Got = ["foo", "string !"] | ["bar", "number !"]
```

Note that there are likely a *lot* of edge cases:

```
type Hmm = TheOneMillionDollarType<["foo", string | number], [string, "a"]>
// type Hmm = ["foo", "a"]
type AlsoHmm = TheOneMillionDollarType<["foo", number], [0, "z"] | [1, "y"]>
// type AlsoHmm = ["foo", "z" | "y"]
type ThirdHmm = TheOneMillionDollarType<["foo", string] | ["bar", number], [string | number, "a"]>;
// type ThirdHmm = ["foo", never] | ["bar", never]
```

Bet that third one isn't what you'd want, but maybe you don't care about that edge case.  Anyway I recommend you test thoroughly, in case it turns out to be `TheThreeDollarFiftyCentType` for your actual use cases.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)